# Reducing a variable DC voltage by a set amount

Tags: microcontroller, analog, signal-processing

I have an analogue signal that's 0-4 V that I want to measure using a micro-controller that only measures up to 3.3 V. I want to reduce the analogue signal by 1 V. I've seen designs using voltage splitters, but the voltage reduction is a function of the input voltage. I need something that's a constant 1V.

Comment: Do you need the output voltage to go negative? That will make this more difficult. Can your ADC handle negative inputs in the first place? Most can't.

Comment: Use a resistor divider to map 0V-4V to 0V-3.3V(VREF). Because if you instead used say a AA battery to literally subtract 1.5V from the sensor voltage, then the range would be (-1.5V to 2.5V). Not good, your 3.3V single-supply microcontroller won't like getting -1.5V at the analog inputs. Can't exceed common-mode input range. Only practical way is to scale it down.  ...or are you  saying the signal you're trying to measure is really in the range 1V-4V (not 0V-4V), and you don't need to be able to measure down to 0V? Does the solution need to be passive, or could you use an op-amp?

Comment: What if there was a simple circuit that dropped it by 1.25 volts?

Comment: I believe I ran into the need for something like this before and used a diode in a pinch when I lacked a proper voltage regulator :) wasn't for measuring though

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off just using a voltage divider, but if you must, you can use a rail-to-rail input-output op-amp as follows

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzWpWf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

While a little lazy for me to use 2 op amps when it can be reduced to only 1, this will accomplish what you are after.

It subtracts 1V from your signal, I presume your circuit does not have negative rails, so will clip anything that falls below 1V on the input

The left most op amp is just giving a buffered 1V ouput, the right op amp is a differential amplifier with a gain of 1.

[image]